# Fill C# DataTable from Oracle PL/SQL Anonymous Block

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, cursor, odp.net

I am trying to execute and return the results of a cursor to my C# program. Below is my code:

```
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"
              declare
              varEmpID              myTable.emp_id%type; 
              varSupID              myTable.supervisor_id%type;
              varNewSupID           myTable.supervisor_id%type;
              varSupActive          myTable.active_ind%type;  

              Cursor C1 is(
                select emp_id,active_ind,supervisor_id
                from myTable where emp_id in 
                ('1','2')) order by emp_id;

            begin                 
              Open C1;                    
              LOOP
                FETCH C1 INTO varEmpID,varSupActive,varSupID;     
                EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;                       
                while (varSupActive<>'Y') loop

                  select m1.supervisor_id, m2.Active_Ind 
                  into varNewSupID,varSupActive
                  from myTable m1, myTable m2 
                  where m1.supervisor_id = m2.emp_id and m1.emp_id = varSupID;

                  varSupID := varNewSupID;

                end loop;

                 open :rc1 for select sup.emp_id, sup.FIRST_NAME,sup.LAST_NAME                    
                 into varEmpID,varFirstName,varLastName
                 from myTable sup 
                 where emp_id = varSupID; 

               END LOOP;
               CLOSE C1;
            EXCEPTION
               WHEN OTHERS THEN
                  raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

            END;

    ";
            cmd.BindByName = true;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("rc1", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            using (cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection(strCon))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);                                     
            }
```

The purpose of cursor is to find an active supervisor for a given set of users. If a user's supervisor in my table is inactive, I need to go up in the hierarchy until I find an active supervisor. There are also some more conditions that I removed here but the point I am trying to make is that I think this can't be achieved using a single SQL statement.

It's clear that I'm not getting all the new supervisors using rc1 cursor as it is inside a loop and it gets over-written. So my C# Output is giving me only the last supervisor. I tried creating table type arrays but even that I have to access using indexes inside a for loop.

I only have read-access to the database so I can not create functions, procedures etc. Is there a way I can write the new supervisor data to a temporary table which is of this program's scope instead of variables so that I can do a select * from that temp table after the loop. Or any other way I can get what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Never tried to execute an anonymous block from .NET. Generally I would create a pipelined function to pass data from Oracle to .NET. See http://psoug.org/reference/pipelined.html

Comment: @PaulStearns I cannot and should not create a function in the database.

Comment: Sorry missed the read only bit. Is this the procedure you need, or has it been simplified? The reason I ask, is you might use the "connect by" syntax and be able to put everything into a single query. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that instead of PLSQL block you can use one hierarchical query like this:

```
select emp_id supervisor_id, last_name, root emp_id
  from (
    select t.*, 
           min(case when active_ind = 'Y' and root <> emp_id 
                    then lvl end) over (partition by root) mlvl
      from (
        select m.*, level lvl,
               connect_by_root(emp_id) root
          from mytable m
          connect by emp_id = prior supervisor_id 
          start with emp_id in (1, 2) ) t )
  where lvl = mlvl
```

Subquery `t` creates supervisor's tree. Next with function `min()` I'm searching for this person who has minimum level (is closest to employee) and is active.

Test data:

```
create table myTable (emp_id number(3), active_ind varchar2(1),  
                      last_name varchar(10), supervisor_id number(3));

insert into mytable values (1, 'Y', 'Brown', 3);
insert into mytable values (2, 'Y', 'Smith', 4);
insert into mytable values (3, 'Y', 'Adams', 6);
insert into mytable values (4, 'N', 'Novak', 5);
insert into mytable values (5, 'Y', 'King',  null);
insert into mytable values (6, 'Y', 'Jones',  null);
```

Output:

```
SUPERVISOR_ID  LAST_NAME  EMP_ID
-------------  ---------  ------
3              Adams           1
5              King            2
```

---

**Edit: Oracle 11 and recursive CTE version:**

```
with t (root, id, act, name, sid, stop) as (
  select emp_id, emp_id, active_ind, last_name, supervisor_id, 0
    from mytable where emp_id in (1, 2)
  union all 
  select t.root, m.emp_id, m.active_ind, m.last_name, m.supervisor_id, 
    case when m.active_ind = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end 
    from t join mytable m on m.emp_id = t.sid and t.stop = 0
  )
select * from t where stop = 1
```

In case of "cycle" troubles use something like `CYCLE id SET cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0` as decribed here: [Recursive Subquery Factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2#cyclic)

Comment: I'm getting ORA-01436: Connect by loop in user data. All I did is replace emp_id with person_id in your query as that is the actual column name.

Comment: never mind. I added NOCYCLE  and it worked like a charm. Never knew that we could achieve such complicated functionality just using a single query.

Comment: But this single query is taking a lot of time to execute even for 5 users. From sql developer, it first took 15 secs, later 2 minutes, 3rd attempt, it kept on running. From Visual Studio Code where my C# application resides, it is stuck and the result set is never coming which is not the case with pl/sql block, despite running it against 900 users at 1 go..

Comment: It's hard to recreate this behavior without data access. Hierarchical queries are slower than others. What You can do is to rewrite `connect by` to `with ... union all ...` version which "stops" after finding first supervisor. This type of query is called recursive CTE and requires Oracle version 11. If You find current answer unusable please unaccept it and wait for others.